# Start a local server for database

Tags: java, database, server, virtual, local

i've been tryin a few things but none of them worked...i'm just a beginner.

What i'd like to do is to write a code that let me connect to the virtual server and not clicking on Properties->Java DB->Start Server

Comment: Are you saying that you want to launch Database Server programmatically?

Comment: Yes, with a button click or by running the file, i don't want to start server any time

Comment: What is this screenshot supposed to show?

Comment: everytime i have to start server manually, i'd like to do that with code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the embedded database driver instead of network client. It will interact directly with the database files, effectively providing an internal DB server in your application.

See this for further reference: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-apache-derby-java-db-via-jdbc

NB: I do not think it is safe to use multiple embedded clients with a single datafile simultaneously, so if that's your case, you'll need to run db server as an OS service and start it.

Comment: Problem is starting virtual server, not database connection.
Before connecting to "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database i have to start virtual server....

Comment: `localhost:1527` in your jdbc url shows that you are connecting to the db through a network client. You will not need to start a server if you change this to the embedded driver url.